# Run shell script for every file in directory

Tags: linux, bash, unix, find, xargs

I have a bunch of files in a directory all named YYYY_MM_DD

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 480K Apr 21 13:17 2012_04_05
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 483K Apr 21 13:17 2012_04_06
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 484K Apr 21 13:17 2012_04_07
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 480K Apr 21 13:17 2012_04_08
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 344K Apr 21 13:17 2012_04_09
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  66K Apr 21 13:17 2012_04_10
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 461K Apr 21 13:17 2012_04_11
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 475K Apr 21 15:09 2012_04_17
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 480K Apr 21 15:10 2012_04_18
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 474K Apr 21 15:10 2012_04_19
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 474K Apr 21 15:10 2012_04_20
```

I have a shell script that accepts a file as a paramater and calculates figures based on the data in the file, i call the script like this

```
sh Calculate.sh MyFile
```

I want to run this shell script for every file in this directory.

How would i go about doing this, xargs ??

Comment: The `find` command will probably be a good start. Here are a few resources on it: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Find.html and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind (gets much more complicated, but worth a look at some point).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried the `find` command with execution ?

My sample will echo the files, but you can call a shell script with the filename as a parameter

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec echo {} \;
```

Comment: This is cool, but how would i pass them files to my Calculate.sh script in order ???

Comment: Ok.. in that case you need to sort out all the files before calling the script.  Try something like this  `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort | xargs -I '{}' Calculate.sh '{}'`

Comment: I understand the command upto xargs, i understand that sort pipes the data into xargs, what is the -I switch and why is there two of '{}' ?? Many thanks.

Comment: When using `-I` you can specify a replace-string. The `'{}'` on `find` command represents the current filename returned, but on `xargs` it doesn't have a special meaning because you can run the script with `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort | xargs -I 'recei_param' echo 'recei_param'` and the output will be the same. You can check more details at [man xargs](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs)

Answer (score 6):

A simple for loop in the shell:

```
for file in *; do sh Calculate.sh "$file"; done
```

Comment: Wouldn't this also run it on itself if Calculate.sh was in the same directory?

Comment: yes it would. To avoid that, with bash, to  loop over all files *not* named Calculate.sh: `shopt extglob nullglob; for file in !(Calculate.sh)`

Answer (score 1):

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | xargs -n 1 -I % Calculate.sh %`

Answer (score 1):

```
./Calculate.sh 2012_04_{05..20}
```