# Using awk to find and replace strings in every file in directory

Tags: awk

I have a directory full of output files, with files with names:
`file1.out`,`file2.out`,..., `fileN.out`.

There is a certain key string in each of these files, lets call it `keystring`. I want to replace every instance of `keystring` with `newstring` in all files.

If there was only one file, I know I can do:

`awk '{gsub("keystring","newstring",$0); print $0}' file1.out > file1.out`

Is there a way to loop through all N files in awk?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run shell script for every file in directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259836/run-shell-script-for-every-file-in-directory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `find` command for the same. Please make sure you run this on a test file first once it works fine then only run it in your actual path(on all your actual files) for safer side. This also needs `gawk` newer version which has `inplace` option in it to save output into files itself.

```bash
find your_path -type f -name "*.out" -exec awk -i inplace -f myawkProgram.awk {} +
```

Where your `awk` program is as follows: as per your shown samples(`cat myawkProgram.awk` is only to show contents of your awk program here).

```bash
cat myawkProgram.awk
{
  gsub("keystring","newstring",$0); print $0
}
```

---

---

2nd option would be pass all `.out` format files into your `gawk` program itself with `-inplace` by doing something like(but again make sure you run this on a single test file first and then run actual command for safer side once you are convinced by command):

```bash
awk -i inplace '{gsub("keystring","newstring",$0); print $0}' *.out
```

Answer (score 1):

sed is the most ideal solution for this and so integrating it with find:

```bash
find /directory/path -type f -name "*.out" -exec sed -i 's/keystring/newstring/g' {} +
```

Find files with the extension .out and then execute the sed command on as many groups of the found files as possible (using + with -exec)